# Giving input of multiple rasters in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, expression, map-algebra

I want to add-up more than 100 raster datasets to derive the sum of all.
Adding all these one by one in calculator using basic algebra expression is time consuming.

Can anybody suggest me how can I add-up all these rasters using a short expression?

You can suggest me any other tool in ArcGIS Desktop too.

Comment: See https://community.esri.com/thread/25945

Comment: Use cell statistics tool. If  they do not overlap create  a big one of zeros.